# how to change float 5.0 to number 5 in list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following list

```
X=[[[0, 'rating'], [1, 4.0], [2, 5.0], [1, 5.0], [0, 4.0], [8, 5.0], [3, 2.0], [5, 5.0], [4, 3.0], [2, 5.0]]]
y=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

And I want to fit with `sklearn.linear_model` in order to classify and count the accuracy of the training data.

By using the following code

```
classifier = Perceptron(tol=1e-5, random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X,y)
```

I got this error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'rating'`
I guess the problem is the float 5.0, but how can I simply change it? I tried with `[[int(x) for x in x[1]]]`

Comment: How was created `X` ? By `read_csv(file, header=False)` ? If yes, remove `header=False`

Comment: It was created with header=None

Comment: Super, just remove it. It is used if no header in csv, here seems csv has header.